# 2 sets of multivalued attributes

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have multivalue attribute which I need to store in 2 different tables. It represents qualificiations for certain jobs. One table is for workers profiles and another for company. Company table states which qualification it needs. Profile of worker table stores data about his qualifications.

My problem is how to store qualification attribute so I dont have two tables which both have full list of all qualifications.

Comment: Create a table `qualification` that stores that information and reference that from the works and company tables

Comment: Yes I was thinking about it, but then I will have one null value in my table...here is the photo for better explanation. https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501405228101